# clearcase rebase permission to specific person

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Is it possible to provide permission to rebase for a specific person only?

Currently i can see clearcase can only "any user allow rebase" option.

If possible please let me know how can I change the stream to allow permission to rebase for a specific person.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to [`cleartool lock -nusers aUser`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lock.htm) a stream, but that will limit *any* command (not just rebase) to that person.

```
cleartool lock -nusers aUser stream:astream@/vobs/apvob
```

The more precise option is to make a pre-op trigger on rebase (with [`cleartool mktrtype`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-44&lang=en)), which test the user and stream and allows or denied the rebase based on those two parameters.

```
cleartool mktrtype -ucmobject -all -preop rebase_start -execunix 'yourScript' -execwin 'ccperl yourScript.pl"' UCM_BLOCK_REBASE
```

See for instance this "[Role-based preoperation trigger script](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_ucm_trggr_role1.htm?lang=en)" (a bit too complex for your case, but which can give some idea about a possible implementation of the preop trigger script).