# Clearcase CQ restriction for Specific Stream

Tags: clearcase-ucm, clearquest, clearcase-automation

I am working on Clearcase/Clearquest in which I have to create the CQ's for defect for the developers. Now the defect is to be delivered in old stream and in current stream also. So for each defect I have to create 3 CQ for single developer. Say I have three stream :

1. 8.0_dev
2. 9.0_dev
3. 10.0_dev

So I create same defect CQ for abouve three stream. Now problem is developer dont care to check the CQ of which stream it is . He is committing the code in 8.0_dev branch by taking CQ of 10.0_dev and it creating mess for me to create Release notes. I want to restrict the commit to the respective CQ assigned to stream. I want Clearcase gives error if CQ assigned to 8.0_dev is used for committing in any other stream, it must be used in commit in  8.0_dev and nowhereelse.

Please advise me how I implement this.

Answer (score 0):

One possible lead a a preop trigger on the deliver operation (with a [`cleartool mktrtypr`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-44&lang=en) similar to the one I mentioned in "[`clearcase rebase` permission to specific person](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921034/6309)").

In your script implementing that check (and called by the trigger), display the [ClearCase environment variables](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/env_ccase.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-6-4) which [are available](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21120991), and see if one would mention an UCM activity named after the CQ you created. That would mean the currently set activity is not the right one, and you can exit -1.

Comment: I have not worked on any trigger yet on ClearCase as I am novince on Clearcase. Here, I am working on windows platform, So can you advise step by step process how I can achieve this.

Comment: Sûre, thé link I mention in the answer provides an example

Comment: I check the link and its about the rebase to particular person, But I want the linking between clearquest and clearcase UCM so that CQ connect to specific stream when assigned.

Comment: Yes, it is just a start. Replace rebase by deliver, and call a script that dumps environment variables, that should be enough to get you started.